# Minecraft Fabric Mixins | Injection

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I need to inject some code to method `register(String id, Item item)`, but there're overloads there.
How can I do this?
[`register` overloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIIdp.png)

I tried this:

```
@Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "register(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/minecraft/item/Item;)V")
    private static void register(String id, Item item, CallbackInfoReturnable<Item> info) {
        //...
        info.setReturnValue(Items.register(new Identifier(id), i));
    }
```

Or this:

```
@Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "register")
    private static void register(String id, Item item, CallbackInfoReturnable<Item> info) {
        //...
        info.setReturnValue(Items.register(new Identifier(id), i));
    }
```

But it's not working...

```
Invalid descriptor on mixin->@Inject::register(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/minecraft/item/Item;Lorg/spongepowered/asm/mixin/injection/callback/CallbackInfoReturnable;)V!
Expected
(Lnet/minecraft/block/Block;Lorg/spongepowered/asm/mixin/injection/callback/CallbackInfoReturnable;)V
but found
(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/minecraft/item/Item;Lorg/spongepowered/asm/mixin/injection/callback/CallbackInfoReturnable;)V
```